# How to print exception stack trace of Objective-C exceptions with GNU runtime and without GNUStep?

Tags: objective-c, exception, stack-trace, printstacktrace

I have an Objective-C app build on Linux with GCC 4.3 using *no* specific framework (only GNU-runtime). I am using Objective-C exceptions (via the '-fobjc-exceptions' compiler flag).

Now I want to print the stack trace of such an exception when I caught some.
Or what would make me even happier: put the trace in a string or some kind of structure to evaluate or print it later on.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no more knowledge is floating in, here is what I found out by myself:

At least under Linux I can use the GNU extensions `backtrace` and `backtrace_symbols` to get addresses of the call stack and the corresponding symbols. This helps a little but is far away from the information that gdb gives. There are neither line numbers nor arguments values.

With the glibc extension `dladdr` I can get similar information but not further.

This is still not exactly what I'm looking for but no one got so clause – so I would accept my own answer :(.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSArray * stack = [NSThread callStackSymbols];
```

It may help.

Comment: As you have seen I required _no_ specific founation (like Cocoa or GNUStep).